# Brain shunt draining

Tags: surgery, procedure-purposes, shunt

A shunt inserted into the brain to relieve the pressure from Normal Pressure Hydrocephalus drains into the peritoneal cavity. Why could it not simple drain into an external container?

Comment: And get an infection from an ascending bacterium??

Answer (score -1):

When you lose fluid from your body and if you don't replace the constituents, you'll be deficient in those. CSF when drains into the peritoneal cavity, it gets absorbed into body circulation. But when it drains externally, it's like constantly vomiting or having constant diarrhoea. You become dehydrated, you lose the electrolytes etc.

Comment: Welcome to Health SE! Here on Health, we [*strongly encourage*](http://meta.health.stackexchange.com/q/1) using references. They are the only way in which we can tell if information is reliable or not. If you are struggling to find good sources, check out, [What are reliable sources?](http://meta.health.stackexchange.com/q/112) If you want to learn more about our site's stance on answers without references, check out, [Should answers without references be immediately deleted?](http://meta.health.stackexchange.com/q/283) Thanks :)